# STM32F0 input to output latency - interrupt

Tags: stm32, interrupt, hal

I've got the device running at 48MHz and am simply using one input pin in interrupt mode to set an output high (setting low is done after a period is elapsed.

I'm surprised to see that the best latency I can get is about 2.8us. I'm using the HAL libraries to handle the interrupt but am writing to the output directly as eventually I might need multiple outputs to be set at once.

Is there anything that can be done to reduce this?

Here is my listing output.

```
    void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
    {
    800089c:    b580        push    {r7, lr}
    800089e:    b082        sub sp, #8
    80008a0:    af00        add r7, sp, #0
    80008a2:    0002        movs    r2, r0
    80008a4:    1dbb        adds    r3, r7, #6
    80008a6:    801a        strh    r2, [r3, #0]

            GPIOB->BSRR |= 0b0100000000000000;
    80008a8:    4b05        ldr r3, [pc, #20]   ; (80008c0 <HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback+0x24>)
    80008aa:    699a        ldr r2, [r3, #24]
    80008ac:    4b04        ldr r3, [pc, #16]   ; (80008c0 <HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback+0x24>)
    80008ae:    2180        movs    r1, #128    ; 0x80
    80008b0:    01c9        lsls    r1, r1, #7
    80008b2:    430a        orrs    r2, r1
    80008b4:    619a        str r2, [r3, #24]

    }
    80008b6:    46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
    80008b8:    46bd        mov sp, r7
    80008ba:    b002        add sp, #8
    80008bc:    bd80        pop {r7, pc}
    80008be:    46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
    80008c0:    48000400    .word   0x48000400
```

Comment: You don't need to `|=` to the BSRR register, it's purpose is to avoid the read-modify-write sequence. Use just `GPIOB->BSRR = 0b0100000000000000;`

Comment: Nothing here accounts for (2.8x48=) 134 cycles of latency.  Try disassembling directly from the vector function if you what to know what is there.  Maybe you need to ditch the HAL and write your own interrupt handler.

Comment: Perhaps instead of using a callback, you want to hook directly into the ISR in Core/Src/stm32f0xx_it.c ? It has "user code" sections that are preserved.

Comment: I'd also point out that compiling your Debug builds with -Og rather than -O0 produces just as good a debugging experience, but with much less bloat in the generated code. (The size is generally not that much more than -Os.) I'd be interested to know if just changing that makes a difference to your latency.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone who left comments, I looked into all of them and have managed to get down to about 660ns now. I think that's possibly the best achievable.

Changing the `|=` to the BSRR register saved about 100ns.

The bulk of the time was saved by moving the output assertion from the HAL callback function to the `EXTI4_15_IRQHandler` and doing the pin assertion first. In my case there are no other pins that can cause that interrupt so I figure I don't really need to check the source. Checking the source appears to take about 300ns.

I also have another `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler` call in the `EXTI4_15_IRQHandler` for a pin that I might have configured as an interrupt at one point (but isn't now).

I've ditched HAL completely; I assume I just needed to write something to clear the interrupt i.e. `EXTI->PR =  (1<<15);` (it works anyway).

The only problem is that now every time I force an update to the source files, the program puts the calls to HAL back in.

Comment: If you open your .ioc file in CubeMX, select System Core->NVIC, then click on the Code Generation tab, you can enable/disable the ISR calling the HAL for each interrupt.